# How to flatten 30 columns into 1 column, based on 4+ unique identifiers in SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

For example, my current table, that I created pulling the columns and renaming them based of off another table, currently looks like this:

```
ID1 | ID2 | Date_1 | Date_2 | ExternalJob 5 | JobIssue 1...|JobIssue30|
```

I would like to get to the point where there is only one JobIssue column with the JobIssues 1-30 going vertically instead of horizontally, essentially flattening the data.

Methods I have tried are pivot and joins but no luck thus far since I have to group them by more than one specific ID1, ID2, Date_1, Date_2, and ExternalJob 5.

So there is a lot of detail, some jobs could have only 1 issue code but up to 30.

At the end of the day I would love to have a table that resembles:

```
ID1 | ID2 | Date_1  | Date_2  | ExternalJob 5 | JobIssue
ID1 | ID2 | Date_1  | Date_2  | ExternalJob 5 | JobIssue
ID1 | ID2 | Date_1  | Date_2  | ExternalJob 5 | JobIssue
ID3 | ID5 | Date_23 | Date_45 | ExternalJob 7 | JobIssue
ID1 | ID2 | Date_10 | Date_20 | ExternalJob 2 | JobIssue
ID1 | ID4 | Date_1  | Date_2  | ExternalJob 9 | JobIssue
ID3 | ID4 | Date_17 | Date_6  | ExternalJob 5 | JobIssue
```

With the JobIssue pulling on its unique identifiers

The JobIssues were all a string that were eventually delimited from a .txt file.

Comment: Do the first 5 variables define a unique key for the table? If so then just use PROC TRANSPOSE. That is what it is for.

Comment: Which SAS tool are you using, SAS DI or EG or Base? This question doesn't lend itself well to SQL in terms of SAS, are you required to use SQL to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

@Joyce L
What you need to do is `UNPIVOT`

> Pivot/Unpivot documentation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

PIVOT is when you want to make rows into columns, though you are trying to do the opposite, which is known as UNPIVOT.

Give it a try and let us know how it goes.

Comment: If this is SAS, it won't support Pivots :(

Comment: I am using SAS 9.4 and proc SQL. So far I have been unsuccessful with the unpivot function. I will try to check your version. Thank you.